# Как сделать вывод других моделей товара?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как сделать такой функционал на woocommerce чтобы в карточке товара, и на странице товара, выводились другие модели этого же товара? Подскажите в какую сторону копать.

Сайт пример: https://www.climat365.com.ua/

1. Страница товара
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Карточка товара в магазине

[image: карточка товара в магазине]

Comment: а чем вас не устраивают вариации?

Comment: так же это можно сделать через апсейлы